# How to split a string if it contains "/" in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a line like this in excel

```
date type price
03/21/2022  payment 3500/3500
```

how can I make it so that excel itself understands and separates them by number /
like this
It's come

```
03/21/2022 PAYMENT 3500/3500
```

excel wrote down

```
03/21/2022 PAYMENT 3500
03/21/2022 PAYMENT 3500
```

Maybe through a formula?
I do not know how to do it

Comment: You can use power query and split by delimiter

Comment: Use the `TEXTSPLIT` function and split on the `<space>`. If you don't have that function, there are numerous examples in this forum using `FILTERXML` or even replacing spaces with multiple spaces.  Please do some research and show what you have tried.